# Missing requirement: ApacheBatikBridge/GVT/Scripting1.6(org.apache.batik.bridge 1.6.0) requires 'bundle org.apache.batik.css [1.6.0,1.7.0)

Tags: java

I am using Eclipse mars.2(4.5.2) and working with BIRT framework.
When I am trying to export the product I am getting the below error

```
Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.

 Software being installed: x 1.0.0 (x 1.0.0)
 Missing requirement: Apache Batik Bridge/GVT/Scripting 1.6.0.v201011041432 (org.apache.batik.bridge 1.6.0.v201011041432) requires 'bundle org.apache.batik.css [1.6.0,1.7.0)' but it could not be found

 Cannot satisfy dependency:

 Cannot satisfy dependency:
```

I even tried with Feature project which will include the different versions of the same plugin in build path while exporting the product. But still it didn't work.

Comment: can anybody have a solution for it